# PDFBox FileNotFoundException found with JProfiler

Tags: java, exception, pdfbox, jprofiler

I tried to optimize my test2.jar application using JProfiler. I noticed, that the most of time is spent in exceptions. However I can't locate the root cause for these exceptions. Both "load" and "save" are under my inspections.

Invitation.pdf is created using PDF-XChange Editor 9.0.352. PDF version is 1.7. It is empty document containing one form field, but the same problem exists with other more complicated pdf documents.

Do I have something wrong in my code or is there a bug in PDFBox 2.0.26 or JProfiler 13.0.3 trial version?

```
package com.home.tests.test2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;

public class Test2
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        try {
            File template = new File("C:\\apps\\PDFBox-2.0.26\\test", "Template.pdf");
            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(template);
//          TODO: Fill in form fields
            document.save("Invitation.pdf");
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception caught:");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("Completed writing Invitation.pdf with success.");
    }
}
```

When I run the jar there seems to be nothing wrong with it:

> C:\apps\PDFBox-2.0.26\test>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_341\bin\java" -jar  Test2.jar
> Completed writing Invitation.pdf with success.

However JProfiler found [a lot of exceptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2BlM.png)

Comment: The current PDFBox versions are 1.8.16 and 2.0.26. Use these.

Answer (score 0):

These exceptions do not have to propagate to your code, they can be thrown and caught in library code.

To see the internal call structure in the library, add

```
org.apache.pdfbox.
```

to the call tree filters in the profiling settings.